# Automate Chatter Post to Specific Users When Creating Log a Call Record

Tags: chatter, notification, after-trigger, activityhistory

I'm hoping that there is someone who can assist me with an automation/trigger question with regard to using Log a Call and Chatter integration.

When using Log a Call, one of our teams has requested additional functionality to leverage chatter. When creating a new Log a Call Activity, they would like to specify one or multiple users to notify about the Log a Call Actity they are creating.

e.g.:
@John Doe, @Jane Smith - {{Log a Call Subject}}

Would someone please assist or point me in the right direction of how I could add specific users to the Log a Call record that is created in chatter?

Currently, users are using Log a Call and then going into Chatter, copying the Log a Call activty and then re-Posting in chatter the copied Log a Call details and adding specific users (@User) to the chatter post.

Ultimately, the desired end result is to notify specifc users when a call is Logged.

Thank you all for your help, your assistance is greatly appreciated!

​~Ryan

Comment: I'm only sharing this because you tagged it with `after-trigger` so I am assuming you are intending to do this with a trigger. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/connectapi_examples.htm

Comment: Process builder would be worth looking at, or flow.  The trick is how to define the users who need to be notified.  I assine it's something you can determine contextually, like contact owner.  Otherwise, how do you imagine users entering the information on who to copy?

Comment: @Jesse Milburn - I tagged it with after-trigger to reach out to people like yourself to see if I should be using Apex coding and a trigger to reach the desired result, or if I shouldn't bother with investigating triggers.

Comment: @gorav - Great suggestion. I've considered using Process builder or a flow, but the biggest issue I'm having is with limited real-estate in the 'Log a Call' quick action window. There are upward of 24 different internal contacts that could be used, and I just don't have the screen space for that many check-boxes. Do you know if it's possible to leverage the 'Assigned To' and Multiple-Users functionality in the Quick-Action window for Log a Call?

Comment: Have you considered using a choice element or a dynamic choice?  You should be able to create a picklist to choose the user.

Comment: I haven't used a dynamic choice yet. Would I need to create a new dynamic choice field, and then add it to the Log a Call Layout? If yes, do you have any suggestions for what script I would need to write to post to chatter with the selections made from the new dynamic choice field? I'm not entirely sure how to tie the two together and then post to chatter with those specific selections.  Thank you very much for your help!